# Get contenteditable div value in angular

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have a contenteditable div like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true" ng-model="name">{{ name }}</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="checkScope()" value="Click me">
```

In my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('sbAdminApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Adrian';

    $scope.checkScope = function(){
        console.log($scope.name);
    }
});
```

How can I get the latest value of contenteditable div using scope when I click the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need a directive to work this

```
app.directive('contenteditable', [function() {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {

        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            // view -> model (when div gets blur update the view value of the model)
            element.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(element.html());
                });
            });

            // model -> view
            ctrl.$render = function() {
                element.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
            };

            // load init value from DOM
            ctrl.$render();

            // remove the attached events to element when destroying the scope
            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                element.unbind('blur');
                element.unbind('paste');
                element.unbind('focus');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and you can use it like this

```
<div contenteditable="true" ng-model="name">{{ name }}</div>
```

here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ri0SV3qk1y4NFyE0EJD6?p=preview)

Comment: I want to update the scope value,so how can I get current editable div scope(Like in current case "name") inside element.bind function.

Comment: directive is updating the `$scope.name` property

Comment: Great.I am going to wrong direction..Thanks for your last comment. +1

Comment: :) glad to help you cheerz